# My program is showing many errors, "error: no matching function for call to 'getPercentScore'"

Tags: c++

I have a program that has to read two input files and sort some data from the two files. I have figured most of the things out but I keep trying to pass a stricter array into my function but it is not working.

```
int main()
{
    int labNumber=8;
    string labName = "MATH ANYONE";
    printHeader(labName, labNumber);

    ifstream    infile;             //INPUT input file stream

    struct test {
        string firstName;           //INPUT student first name
        string lastName;            //INPUT student last name
        string tempfirstName;       //INPUT temporary first name used to place into actual
        string templastName;        //INPUT temporary last name used to place into actual
        string tempId;              //INPUT temporary id used to compare with actual
        string studentId;           //INPUT student id
        double courseScore;         //OUTPUT student score %
        char courseGrade;           //OUTPUT student letter grade
        string answers;             //INPUT student answer
    };
    test *table[30];
```

this is just part of my code; I have one input file called functions.cpp

```
    for (int i=0;i<studentCount;i++)
    {
        double percent=0;
        getPercentScore(table[30], key);
    }
```

functions.cpp:

```
double getPercentScore(test *, string key)

{
    double tempscore=0;
    double percent;
    for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        if (table[i].answers[i] == key[i])
        {
            tempscore = tempscore + 2; //add two if answer is correct
        }
        else if (table[i].answers[i] == '_')
        {
            tempscore = tempscore + 0;//add zero if answer if unanswered
        }
        else
        {
            tempscore = tempscore - 1;//subtract one for wrong answer
        }
    }
    percent = tempscore/40;
    percent = percent*100;
    return percent;
}
```

my program has been giving me this error and I do not know how to solve it:

../lab8.cpp:112:3: error: no matching function for call to 'getPercentScore'
                getPercentScore(table[30], key);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../lab8.cpp:33:8: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'test *' to 'test *' for 1st argument
double getPercentScore(test *, string key);

Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: Caution, if you declare `test *table[30];`, using `table[30]` later will cause trouble.

Comment: If you pass `test[30]`, you are passing a lonely position of your array to the method.  I think you mean `getPercentScore(test[i], key);` in your loop?

Comment: You forgot to post all the #include directives. They are important, never edit them out before posting your question.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to create the test array:

```
test table[30];
```

At functions.cpp declare function getPercentScore() as:

```
double getPercentScore(test tbl[], string key)
```

also, replace any reference of table inside getPercentScore() body with tbl.

If you wish to know the size of the array, pass it as an extra parameter like:

```
size_t size = sizeof(table) / sizeof(test);
for (int i=0;i<studentCount;i++)
{
    double percent=0;
    getPercentScore(table, size, key);
}
```

Hope I helped you...